# Not able to retrieve data array from CI hook

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following hook ran when a user gets to any page on my site. I'm trying to figure out how to have a page access the $data array with the current user object attached to the data array if the current user is found. When I visit a page in my cms after I've logged in it says that the data array is NULL when I run a vardump on the variable.

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        dump_exit($this->data);
    }
}


<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Sys_prescript extends CI_Controller {
    public $data = array();    
    function initial_run()
    { 
        $public_access = array('login', 'registration');
        $current_class = $this -> router -> fetch_class();
        $user_id = $this -> session -> userdata('user_id');
        if ($user_id == FALSE)
        {
            if (!in_array($current_class, $public_access))
            {
                redirect('login', 'refresh');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ((!is_numeric($user_id)) || (strlen($user_id) < 5)) {
                $this->session->unset_userdata('user_id'); 
                $this->session->sess_destroy();   
                redirect('login', 'refresh');
            }
            else {
                $this->load->model('user_model', 'user');    
                $current_user = $this -> user -> get($user_id);
                if (!is_object($current_user)) {
                    $this -> session -> unset_userdata('user_id');
                    $this -> session -> sess_destroy();
                    redirect('login', 'refresh');
                }
                else {
                    $this->data['current_user'] = $current_user;
                }  

                if (in_array($current_class, $public_access))
                {
                    redirect('dashboard', 'refresh');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hook should be just a class, you dont need to extend the CI_Controller again. Think that you are extend the CI again that means you are creating at new CI object so they dont know each other. You just should need to create a class and inside the class if you want to use any CI variable, library, model you need to create an CI instance

`$CI =& get_instance();`

Then Use `$CI->data();` where `$CI` is CI_Controller

And what kinds of hook you running? if you set your data in controller function you should use `post_controller`